# Strange interaction between jdom and ssis

Tags: jdom, ssis

I apologize for the long post, but this problem is not easily stated.

I recently wrote a piece of Java to reconfigure some SSIS packages for a colleague, using jdom to parse and manipulate the XML. The program worked, but the resulting files crashed. We were able to trace the crash to an odd mostly-nonprinting character in the original files, which was not reproduced in the files written by jdom.

What's strange about this character is that it doesn't show up in all editors. The Oxygen XML editor, for example, doesn't even see it. However, in notepad, the original copyright notice appears like this:

```
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="TaskContact">Execute SQL Task; Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft 
SQL Server v9; Â© 2004 Microsoft Corporation; All Rights     
Reserved;http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support/default.asp;1</DTS:Property>
```

and the transformed version of the same element:

```
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="TaskContact">Execute SQL Task; Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft 
SQL Server v9; © 2004 Microsoft Corporation; All Rights 
Reserved;http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support/default.asp;1</DTS:Property>
```

(the problem character is the Â just before the copyright symbol)

Running a global replace on the packages in question, where Â -> "" and © -> "(c)", made the problem go away, but now it turns out that the problem comes back when unmodified elements are put into the modified packages, so now I'm not as sure what is at the root of the problem.

Again, I'm sorry for the long post, but I didn't want to leave out any details. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated; I'm pretty well stumped.

My colleague will be sending me error messages from his attempts to load these, I can post those if they're useful.

Comment: What you are reconfiguring in SSIS via jdom?

Comment: I'm rejiggering a bunch of dtsx packages for the data warehouse, helping the DB team clean up. Specificially, normalizing some element names and inserting missing elements whose makeup can be determined programmatically.

Comment: Ah, I was going to suggest looking at [PacMan](http://pacman.codeplex.com/) but it sounds like you are already familiar with the object model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to the root of the problem: writing in one encoding and reading another. See my answer to this question. [£ becomes Â£ Why? XML ISO encoding issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349176/becomes-a-why-xml-iso-encoding-issue/7349567#7349567)
Just replace the pound sign, £, with the copyright symbol, © (unicode U+00A9). Hopefully you can find the place where the encoding mixup is occurring.

Comment: Thanks for that. I found that answer while I was searching, and while it hasn't got me sorted, it's helped me look in better places. In the meantime, I made a FileReader and called its getEncoding() method, it says "Cp1252". I set my XMLFormatter's output encoding to that, and the characters seem to come out right but JDOM can't read the resulting file. Since I had a two-phase process, this was a problem.  I've combined the phases and I expect a report on whether it worked, will post results.

Comment: @JonKiparsky. Using a FileReader could be the problem. The encoding for the reader may not match the "real" encoding of the content, and this is supported by the evidences in this case. I always recommend using byte streams instead of character streams.