# Android XML Parsing

Tags: android

My XML is 

**Die Hollenparty, Comedyserie, 39/55 Min. Staffel 1,  Folge 13 | Serie**


but in android textview it is displaying like this. It added (Â) 

Die Hollenparty, Comedyserie, 39/55 Min. Staffel 1,Â  Folge 13 | Serie

Comment: seems like a character encoding issue to me, what charset is the XML using?

Comment: doesn't look like xml to me. (your issue is definitely encoding related, probably your space is a special char.

Comment: character encoding is utf8 (http://5.39.219.67/~tvinfo/api_program_details.php?pid=149685&xcode=02)

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349176/becomes-why-xml-iso-encoding-issue

Comment: Can you please further guide me how to fix this problem? I didnt understand the solution in above same question..

Comment: problem fixed..thanks to all for your response.

Answer (score 0):

there are plenty of examples out there here is an example ,using XMLpullParser  [CLICk](http://d-codepages.com/index.php/android/coding-advanced/24-xml-parsing-using-xmlpullparser-loading-images-using-lazy-loading)